# Getting an existing React App up and running

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm trying to get an already existing React App running locally on my Mac. I have all the source files, and have node.js installed on my machine.

When I run `npm install` I'm greeted with a long list of deprecations and npm ERRors. A list so long it far exceeds the Stack overflow character limit. Here's how it *ends*.

```
npm ERR! 2 warnings generated.
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/libsass/src/util.cpp:3:
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1614:25: warning: loop variable 'numerator' creates a copy from type 'const std::__1::basic_string<char>' [-Wrange-loop-construct]
npm ERR!         for (const auto numerator : numerators)
npm ERR!                         ^
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1614:14: note: use reference type 'const std::__1::basic_string<char> &' to prevent copying
npm ERR!         for (const auto numerator : numerators)
npm ERR!              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR!                         &
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1616:25: warning: loop variable 'denominator' creates a copy from type 'const std::__1::basic_string<char>' [-Wrange-loop-construct]
npm ERR!         for (const auto denominator : denominators)
npm ERR!                         ^
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1616:14: note: use reference type 'const std::__1::basic_string<char> &' to prevent copying
npm ERR!         for (const auto denominator : denominators)
npm ERR!              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR!                         &
npm ERR! 2 warnings generated.
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/libsass/src/values.cpp:3:
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/libsass/src/values.hpp:4:
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1614:25: warning: loop variable 'numerator' creates a copy from type 'const std::__1::basic_string<char>' [-Wrange-loop-construct]
npm ERR!         for (const auto numerator : numerators)
npm ERR!                         ^
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1614:14: note: use reference type 'const std::__1::basic_string<char> &' to prevent copying
npm ERR!         for (const auto numerator : numerators)
npm ERR!              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR!                         &
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1616:25: warning: loop variable 'denominator' creates a copy from type 'const std::__1::basic_string<char>' [-Wrange-loop-construct]
npm ERR!         for (const auto denominator : denominators)
npm ERR!                         ^
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1616:14: note: use reference type 'const std::__1::basic_string<char> &' to prevent copying
npm ERR!         for (const auto denominator : denominators)
npm ERR!              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR!                         &
npm ERR! 2 warnings generated.
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/binding.cpp:1:
npm ERR! In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:58:
npm ERR! In file included from /Users/USER/.node-gyp/16.13.1/include/node/node.h:63:
npm ERR! In file included from /Users/USER/.node-gyp/16.13.1/include/node/v8.h:30:
npm ERR! /Users/USER/.node-gyp/16.13.1/include/node/v8-internal.h:492:38: error: no template named 'remove_cv_t' in namespace 'std'; did you mean 'remove_cv'?
npm ERR!             !std::is_same<Data, std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data);
npm ERR!                                 ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR!                                      remove_cv
npm ERR! /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/type_traits:776:50: note: 'remove_cv' declared here
npm ERR! template <class _Tp> struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS remove_cv
npm ERR!                                                  ^
npm ERR! 1 error generated.
npm ERR! make: *** [Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o] Error 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/USER/Desktop/it-cc/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.6.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/USER/Desktop/it-cc/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/USER/Desktop/it-cc/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1
```

I have tried the following:

- Making sure all lock files & node_module directory is deleted
- Cleared cache by `npm cache clear --force`
- `npm audit fix`

I'm a bit of a noob to React and would really appreciate any help!

package.json contents:

```
{
  "name": "marketing-roi",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.10.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it an M1 mac? Those errors are node trying and failing to compile a native module in C++, which would make sense if your architecture is different.

Comment: Maybe it is due to M1 processor.

Comment: @JaredSmith It's an Intel i5

Comment: @DavidMartini well, at any rate, it has nothing to do with React: for some reason libsass isn't compiling. Do you have xcode and clang installed? And can you post the package.json contents to see if we can replicate?

Comment: @JaredSmith Updated my post with the contents of the package.json. I do not believe I have either of those installed.

Comment: What version of node.js? Also, node-sass is deprecated and is the source of your issue, so you may want to try to dump it. You'll need a C++ compiler to use it.

Comment: @JaredSmith npm -v returns 8.1.2. Good to know. This is an app that was built 1-2 years ago I believe.

Comment: @DavidMartini that's your npm version, not your node.js version. What does `node --version` give?

Comment: @JaredSmith Whoops! node --version returns v16.13.1

Comment: Yeah, that's current, and that's a problem. Just replace `node-saas` in your package.json with `sass` per [the deprecation announcement](https://sass-lang.com/blog/libsass-is-deprecated#how-do-i-migrate). It's a pure JS implementation of sass so no compiling required and it's maintained.

Comment: @JaredSmith Thanks for steering me in the right direction dude! I'll dig into this and report back :) I had a feeling there might be some version conflicts but am quite new to node and npm as you may have guessed!

Comment: I changed `node-sass` to `sass` in my package.json and it returns an error that `No matching version found for sass@^4.14.1`

Comment: Found the latest version of sass was 1.47.0. Updated in package.json and we have successfully compiled!

Comment: @DavidMartini glad you got it sorted out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to replace `node-sass` with `sass` in my package.json file, and editing the version to a valid one (in my case I chose the latest build 1.47.0).

I'm running a current version of node on my machine and was specifying an old version node-sass that was no longer supported in my package.json file since the app was built a couple years ago. [Deprecation Announcement](https://sass-lang.com/blog/libsass-is-deprecated#how-do-i-migrate)

Thanks to [@Jared Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3757232/jared-smith)